# questions about binary search tree

Tags: trees

Show that every n-node binary search tree is not equally likely (assuming items are inserted in random order), and that balanced trees are more probable than straight-line trees.

How is it prove mathematical?

Please, help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Take a look at the [Geometric Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and use $p=0.5$.